# How do you organize your data in android app?

Tags: android, data-structures, architecture

I develop my first android application. This is pretty simple app. It has a number of articles (pieces of text) which have title, short description, content, etc. These articles are grouped be groups/categories. The number of articles (and actually all data) is static and will not be changed.

How do you store such information in your android apps? How to store it to be able to add translations in the nearest future?

What data structure to use?

I know how to localize application. But I can create only array of strings with one dimension, as I have understood.

Comment: try using database like sqlite...

Comment: but how to localize application in with SQLite? SQLite Full Unicode support is optional and not installed by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The number of articles (and actually all data) is static and will not be changed. How do you store such information in your android apps?

If they are not going to be changed, you can package them as resources in your app, such as XML resources in `res/xml/` (and related resource sets).

> How to store it to be able to add translations in the nearest future?

If you package them as resources in your app, you can have translations in different resource sets (e.g., `res/xml-zh/` for Chinese).

> But I can create only array of strings with one dimension, as I have understood.

Any resource in Android can have translations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about translations. But what type of xml to use? "values"? could you explain it more deeply? please.

Comment: Thanks I have figured it out by myself.